# how can i verify if any or all elements are empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash, i want to know if any param does not exist or is empty

how is does not exist? in this case does not exist the param 'b'

```
 {"a"=>"first", "c"=>"5"}
```

and empty element is like this: `"a"=>""`

```
{"a"=>"", "b"=>"b", "c"=>"5"}
```

this is my attempt:

```
array.any?{|_,i| p i.blank?}
```

**output:**

if there is (all or any empty elements) then return true

`[true, false]` output `true`

`[true, false,true]` output `true`

`[true, true]` output `true`

`[true, true, true]` output `true`

`[false, false]` output `false`

`[false, false, false]` output `false`

Comment: Give the example output. Don't write in statement.

Comment: This can be simplified to `array.any?(&:blank?)`, respectively `array.all?(&:blank?)`, if you want to test for _blank_.  Based on your example, _empty_ instead of _blank_ would be perhaps the correct solution, but this is up to you to decide.

Comment: _"i want to know if any param does not exist"_ – you need a list of possible parameters (e.g. `['a', 'b', 'c']`) that you can compare the given parameters to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h = { "a" => "", "c" => "5" }

keys = h.keys
missed_keys = [*keys.first..keys.last] - keys

puts 'Missed Keys'
p missed_keys

puts 'Keys which are having empty values'
p h.filter_map { |k, v| k if v.empty? }
```

Output

```
Missed Keys
["b"]
Keys which are having empty values
["a"]
```

**update:**
To only return true or false.

```
p h.any? { |k, v| v.empty? }
```

output

```
true
```

Comment: Given the example output then.

Comment: @lezaa Okay, I have updated the answer, can you see now?

Comment: in this case [true, false] should return true, only true because exist an empty element

Comment: @lezaa Okay, I have updated again, check it now.

Comment: by any chance, how can i count this %w[name version color] i want to get 3

Comment: @lezaa `p %w[name version color].count` it will print 3 for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ruby has `blank?` function to do this

```
hash = {"a": 1, "c": ""}

def is_missing(hash, key)
  hash[key.to_sym].blank?
end

is_missing(hash, "a") => false 
is_missing(hash, "b") => true 
is_missing(hash, "c") => true
```

Comment: `blank?` method is in rails not in ruby.